# .htaccess rewrite works fine with number but not letters?

Tags: .htaccess

When I write www.example.com/foo/1 it works fine but when i write www.example.com/foo/count or any letter it says

Not Found

The requested URL foo/count was not found on this server.

but everthing works fine when I try foo/12 or any number is passed? whats wrong or what am I missing here?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/? $1.php?key=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? $1.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
```

The pattern [^/]+ matchs any characters 1 or more times except the "/".

Comment: Thank You! Thank You! Thank You! I Spent All of Yesterday and half of today trying to figure this out. thanks a ton!

Comment: @MikeLake - An explanation: `(\d+)` (which is a metacharacter for `[0-9]`) will check for digits only, which is why it wouldn't match characters before. Maybe spend some time [learning regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) so that you understand how they work. :)